# jquery only firing on second click

Tags: jquery, css

i have a dropdown box that when i click it the arrow rotates.how ever the arrow only rotates on the second click.what am i doing wrong?

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <a onclick="UserdropDownDetails()"><div class="triangle1"></div></a>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content ">
    <ul>
     // drop down elements
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.triangle1 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #cecece;
    margin-left: -10px;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.triangle-up {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

code:

```
function flipTriangle() {
                $('.triangle1').on('click', function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass("triangle-up");  //this flips my image but its only working if i click it twice.
                });
            }

function UserdropDownDetails() {
            flipTriangle(); i need this to fire the first time its clicked
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show"); //this shows my drop down,which works fine.

        }
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your `flipTriangle()` function contains a click event so this will only be fired when its clicked. calling the function wont do anything as it still needs to wait until the click event happens.

Comment: Remove the onclick surrounding the toggleClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand this, UserdropDownDetails() function won't fire the $(this).toggleClass("triangle-up");  as it is placed in an onclick event.The functions should be something like

```
function flipTriangle(){

                $(".triangle1").toggleClass("triangle-up");  

}
$('.triangle1').on('click',flipTriangle);
function UserdropDownDetails() {
        flipTriangle();
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show"); 
    }
```

Comment: Awesome.. hope you got what the problem was :)

Answer (score 2):

You are binding event handler in the function `flipTriangle` so the event is attached on first click thus it works on second click.

Move the code outside the function.

```
$(function () {
    $('.triangle1').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("triangle-up"); //this flips my image but its only working if i click it twice.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you should register the event on document ready like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.triangle1').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("triangle-up");  //this flips my image but its only working if i click it twice.
    });
});
```

Or you can just fire after register it at the fist time, but I'm not sure if it makes sense and:

```
function flipTriangle() {
    $('.triangle1').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("triangle-up");  //this flips my image but its only working if i click it twice.
    });
    $('.triangle1').trigger( "click" );
}
```

It will click twice after the fist time if you don't put a condition to fire only at the first time.